# How to prove that the minimum parameters required is equal to the dimension of an object?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

Based on my (very limited) understanding, if an object needs to be expressed in terms of at least $n$-parameters, then it is an $n$-dimensional object.

You can parameterise a circle as:
$$x=rcos(\theta) , y=rsin(\theta)$$
With only one parameter so it is 1-dimensional.

Similarly a sphere can be expressed as:
$$x=rcos(\theta)sin(\phi) , y=rsin(\theta)sin(\phi), z=rcos(\phi)$$

So I think it is technically a 2-dimensional object.

Is there a way to prove that you need at least two variables to parameterise a square (or any polygon) or that you need at least three variables to parameterise a cube (or any three-dimensional object)?

Can this method, if it exists, be used to prove that any $n$-dimensional object needs at least $n$ parameters?

Comment: Do you have a favourite definition of "dimension", or "object" for that matter? As you might imagine, the answer to your question will depend on that.

Comment: @fuglede For dimension I guess it would be the least number of co-ordinates requires to specify a point. For example you need two co-ordinates to specify any point on a sphere; latitude and longitude ($\theta , \phi$). I not sure how to define an object, maybe a bounded figure (a square is bounded by lines, a cube by faces etc.)?

Comment: It seems you're essentially answering your own question then, by *defining* the dimension in terms of the number of parameters needed, at least insofar that you view the parameters as defining coordinates. I'll elaborate a bit in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the only way to answer the question mathematically is by settling on what kind of objects we want to consider, and, afterwards, what the dimension of a given object means.

Now it turns out that mathematicians are generally interested in a plethora of different "objects", many of which have associated notions of dimension. The [Wikipedia article on "dimension"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension) gives a bunch of different examples. For the objects you're considering, what you're asking is indeed so reasonable that we might take it to be the *definition* of the term "dimension", so that we don't even have to proof anything.

To expand a bit on this, note that all of the objects you consider are examples of [topological manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold), which may roughly be described as follows: every point in a topological manifold has a neighbourhood which may be continuously deformed to look like $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$. For example, in you consider a point on a sphere and zoom in enough, you'll eventually be seeing a plane (we can make maps of the Earth)! The number $n$ turns out to be uniquely determined and is called the *dimension* of the manifold.

Now, these neighbourhoods you should think of as describing coordinates close to the point, so that, as you say yourself in your comment above, the dimension is simply the number of real numbers making up the coordinates needed to describe points on the manifold. Thus, if your question had been whether or not it's true that the least number of real numbers you need to describe the object, then this would be true simply *by definition* of "dimension".

However, you're really asking about parameters and not coordinates, so we should also agree on exactly what we mean by the word "parameters". Normally, these would be numbers that together describe the *entire* space, rather than just small neighbourhoods of points; again, the [Wikipedia article provides some discussion of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization). One difference that's clear already from your examples is that different values of the parameters might describe the same points (for the circle, by changing $\theta$ to $\theta + 2\pi$, you end up at the same point), whereas the coordinates we really want to uniquely determine a given point (but then, we will generally need several sets of coordinates to describe the entire object). Nonetheless, as you're essentially saying in the comments, you could use these parameters to describe your coordinate neighbourhoods which on the other means that what you're asking is indeed true, more or less by definition.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that by saying a square needs two parameters to define it then it is two dimensional, but how can we show that you need at least two parameters? A circle can be defined by two parameters but as we can show there is some way to define it with only one then it is, like you said, by definition one dimensional. Is there no way to show that a square cannot be defined by 1 parameter?

Comment: Good question! I kind of swept that under the carpet by saying that if there is an $n$ as in my answer, then it's uniquely determined. So, let's take for granted that the solid square is $2$-dimensional. That is, every point has coordinates described by pairs of numbers. Would one number do? If so, by the definition above, a given point would have neighbourhoods with weird properties: one that could be continuously deformed to $\mathbb R$ and to $\mathbb R^2$ (in a one-to-one fashion). In particular, this would imply that $\mathbb R$ itself could be transformed to $\mathbb R^2$. This [...]

Comment: [...] turns out to be impossible; the precise and general statement is the following: there is no continuous bijective map $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ with a continuous inverse $f^{-1} : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. This follows from the so-called invariance of domain theorem, which it actually requires a fair amount of mathematical machinery to prove. Again, you can [see the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain#Consequences) for some discussion. If you're not already familiar with it, I would suggest starting [...]

Comment: [...] out with understanding the notion of a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) though. Let me once again stress that this is a story about topological manifolds, and that depending on your viewpoint, other answers would apply.

Comment: And maybe I should say that as soon as you understand the various concepts involved in the statement, the case $n = 1$, $m = 2$ isn't too bad; it's probably on Stack Exchange somewhere.